# When discussing job experience, how should it read?

Tags: symbols

Should it read:

Jake has 20+ years experience.

Jake has +20 years experience.

Comment: Between the two choices, pick 20+.

Comment: Better yet: *Jake has over twenty years of experience.*

Comment: Be guided by how it will sound in the person's head when read. Would you *say* "Jake has twenty-plus years experience" or would you *say* "Jake has plus-twenty years experience"?

Answer (score 3):

*20+* is an informal yet concise way to represent *20 or more* or *at least 20*.

In actual formal writing, it's better to write:

> Jake has over twenty years of experience.

On the other hand, *+20* or *20-* is normally never used. *-20* has a different purpose.